# expressing product as Vandermonde determinants

Tags: polynomials, determinant

Is it possible to express the product:
$$ \frac{\prod_{i < j} (a_i - a_j)(b_i - b_j) }{\prod_{i,j} (a_i - b_j) }$$
as the determinant of a single matrix ?

This comes from a [physics paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.4066).  Should be similar to a [Vandermonde determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).

**EDIT**: Obviously, I do not want a $1 \times 1$ matrix whose single entry as the answer.  Why are [Hilbert matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix) or [Toeplitz matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) or [Cauchy matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_determinant), the natural choices then ? Sorry.

Comment: note that this still doesn't fix it, since I could still construct a diagonal matrix with say $a_1 - a_2$ as the first entry, $a_2 - a_3$ as the second entry, and the rest of the product as the third entry, and the rest of the entries as 1. Of course, we could also have a diagonal matrix where the entires are these 'polynomials'.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you should be specific about what you want? A diagonal matrix with that value in the first entry and 1 everywhere else (on the diagonal) will suffice.

You can't request that the coefficients be polynomials, since your determinant has 'degree' -n.

You might want to check out Hilbert matrices, which have entries $\frac {1}{a_i + b_j}$ and determinant $\frac { \prod (a_i - a_j)(b_i-b_j)}{\prod (a_i + b_j) }$.

Comment: @Ofir, the hope was that he would realize that.

Comment: Replace all the $b_i$ by $-b_i$ in the Hilbert matrix and you'll get exactly what the OP wants (up to $\pm 1$).

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Yes, the hope is that OP would realize that, which was my reply to Ofir, who then pulled his comment.

Comment: David is correct, but I have to think about how to fix my wording.